# Can record field updates in OCaml be generalized?

Tags: macros, ocaml, records

I'm a very novice OCaml programmer so please forgive me if this is a stupid/obvious question.  There's *a lot* to absorb and I may have missed this in the documentation.

I have a base of code that's starting to look like this:

```
let update_x p x =
  add_delta p;
  p.x <- x;
  refresh p

let update_y p y =
  add_delta p;
  p.y <- y;
  refresh p

let update_z p z =
  add_delta p;
  p.z <- z;
  refresh p
```

The duplication is starting to bug me because I *want* to write something like this:

```
let update_scalar p scalar value =
    add_delta p;
    magic_reflection (p, scalar) <- value;
    refresh p
```

This way when I update x I can simply call:

```
update_scalar p 'x' value
```

This calls out "macros!" to me but I don't believe OCaml has a macro system.  What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do what you want in plain OCaml. You could write a syntax extension with [camlp4](http://martin.jambon.free.fr/extend-ocaml-syntax.htm) (which is a kind of a macro system, though a different kind than you're probably accustomed to) that would transform

```
UPDATE_FIELD x f y
```

into

```
x.f <- y
```

Alternatively, you could stuff things into a hash table and forgo type safety.

NOTE: The version of camlp4 included in OCaml version 3.10 and later is different than and incompatible with the previous version. For information about the latest version, see [the OCaml tutorial site](http://www.ocaml-tutorial.org/camlp4_3.10).

Comment: Nit: chosing `val` as an identifier name is confusing, `val` is used as a binding in module types.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do quite what you want, but you can greatly reduce the boilerplate with a higher-order function:

```
let update_gen set p x =
  add_delta p;
  set p x;
  refresh p

let update_x = update_gen (fun p v -> p.x <- v)
let update_y = update_gen (fun p v -> p.y <- v)
let update_z = update_gen (fun p v -> p.z <- v)
```

OCaml does have a macro system (camlp4) and it does allow you to implement this kind of thing, with some work.

Comment: This is the right solution most of the time. You can always optimize your code later if it matters. And by all means do us all a favor and do not start relying on camlp4, it's a pile a crap.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above ocaml has macro system. And for this task only small fraction of it is needed :

```
open Printf

type t = { mutable x : float; mutable y : float; mutable z : float; mutable t : int; }

let add_delta p = p.t <- p.t + 1
let refresh p = printf "%d) %.2f %.2f %.2f\n" p.t p.x p.y p.z

DEFINE UPD(x) = fun p v ->
  add_delta p;
  p.x <- v;
  refresh p

let update_x = UPD(x)
let update_y = UPD(y)
let update_z = UPD(z)

let () =
  let p = { x = 0.; y = 0.; z = 0.; t = 0; } in
  update_x p 0.1;
  update_y p 0.3;
  update_z p 2.0
```

Compile with:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package camlp4.macro -syntax camlp4o q.ml -o q
```

See the generated code with :

```
camlp4o Camlp4MacroParser.cmo q.ml
```